# Form data evaluation

Tags: tableau-api

I have a form data wherein tableau I am using the below value to find out the choices for a multiple value question. The question is Could you please indicate one or two areas where we fell short.

the value can be explosives, vehicles, cement etc

I have individually accounted for each of the choices in the below calculated field:

int(contains(lower([Could you please indicate one / two of the following areas where we fell short of meeting your expectations?]),'factory'))

Similarly I have found out for other values:
The calculated fields are hasvehicle, hasfactory etc

But the problem is how can I visualize the same in the form of bars?

All I am able to do is this:

[image]

How can I visualise the same in the form of bars side by side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have one measure on Rows, drag the second measure and drop it in the axis.

[image]

It will result with Measure Names on the Columns shelf and Measure Values on the rows shelf.

[image]